# Haskell: How to unwrap nested maybes in data

Tags: haskell

Newbie here!

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data Supplier = Supplier { 
    nameS :: String,
    country :: Maybe String
}

data Product = Product {
    nameP :: String,
    supplier :: Maybe Supplier
}
```

I need a function that returns a Maybe product's country, or "unknown" if there is a Nothing in the chain.
I could do it like this:

```
productCountry :: Maybe Product -> String
productCountry product =
    case product of
    Just p -> case supplier p of
              Just s -> case country s of
                        Just c -> c
                        Nothing -> "unknown"
              Nothing -> "unknown"
    Nothing -> "unknown"
```

But this is awkward. Another way would be:

```
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

productCountry2 :: Maybe Product -> String
productCountry2 product =
    let countryMaybe = do
        p <- product
        s <- supplier p
        c <- country s
        return c
    in fromMaybe "unknown" countryMaybe
```

I feel like there must be a better way to do it, but I couldn't find it.

What would be the best idiomatic Haskell code for 'productCountry'?

Comment: The second way is pretty much the idiomatic way to do it. The only obvious improvement I see on that is to just have `country s` at the end of the `do` block, instead of pointlessly unwrapping the value and then `return`ing it.

Comment: Or you could not bother with the `do` block, and write it more concisely (although it's more opaque, at least to some) as `let countryMaybe = product >>= supplier >>= country in fromMaybe "unknown" countryMaybe`

Comment: @Robin Nice. Succinct, but a bit 'opaque' indeed - for newbies. Thank you.

Comment: "I need a function that returns a Maybe product's country, or "unknown" if there is a Nothing in the chain. ". Why? Why not just return `Nothing`?

Comment: It's quite advanced, but definitely relevant https://reasonablypolymorphic.com/blog/higher-kinded-data/

Comment: Another approach would be to compose `^?` , `_Just` lenses

Comment: @RobinZigmond, how about making that comment into an answer (well, perhaps simplified using the identity`let x = y in f x` ===  `f y`).  "Opaque" or not, it's hard to imagine a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: There's little reason to avoid `>>=`. You don't have to know exactly how it works in order to recognize that `product >>= supplier` will produce the supplier of an actual product or `Nothing` if the product doesn't exist. People use floating-point arithmetic all the time without knowing exactly how *it* works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting some of my comments into an answer, as suggested:

Your second code snippet:

```
productCountry2 :: Maybe Product -> String
productCountry2 product =
    let countryMaybe = do
        p <- product
        s <- supplier p
        c <- country s
        return c
    in fromMaybe "unknown" countryMaybe
```

is already close to what I would say is idiomatic Haskell. It's certainly many times better than your first snippet, with multiple explicit `case` statements to account for the fact that any `Nothing` result encountered along the way should mean immediate failure. The `Monad` instance for `Maybe` - which you have used in this second snippet, with the `do` block - is there precisely to avoid having to repeat such boilerplate code. (In fact it could be argued that this is what all Monads are really for, with the exception of `IO` which is somewhat "magical".)

I have only 2 suggestions for improving it. The first is that this, from the end of your `do` block:

```
c <- country s
return c
```

is completely equivalent to simply

```
country s
```

This is because all `do` blocks are simply syntactic sugar for uses of the `>>=` operator - your first snippet is equivalent to `country s >>= return`. And this, by the so-called [Right identity law](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws), is the same as `country s`, as used in the second snippet.

The second possible simplification - although I would argue this is more a matter of opinion - is to simply leave out the `do` block altogether and use the "desugared" version:

```
productCountry2 :: Maybe Product -> String
productCountry2 product =
    let countryMaybe = product >>= supplier >>= country
    in fromMaybe "unknown" countryMaybe
```

Finally, as suggested by @K.A.Buhr, you can realise the `let` expression doesn't really gain you a lot here, and simply write this as:

```
productCountry2 :: Maybe Product -> String
productCountry2 product = fromMaybe "unknown" $ product >>= supplier >>= country
```

(Although personally I think the `let` expression is OK here, it is a bit more long-winded, and isn't strictly needed - but I wouldn't criticise it as it separates the monadic expression from the separate use of `fromMaybe` to extract the result and supply `"unknown"` if it happens to be `Nothing`.)

Answer (score 4):

If you are writing a function whose first argument has type `Maybe Something`, it's usually a good sign that you are unnecessarily avoiding `Maybe`'s monad instance.

```
data Supplier = Supplier { 
    nameS :: String,
    country :: Maybe String
}

data Product = Product {
    nameP :: String,
    supplier :: Maybe Supplier
}

productCountry :: Product -> Maybe String
productCountry p = supplier p >>= country
-- Or, using Kleisli composition (requires Control.Monad)
-- productCountry = supplier >=> country
```

If you find yourself with an instance of `Maybe Product`, use the `Maybe` monad again to feed it to `productCountry`.

```
maybeProduct >>= productCountry  -- Just "somelandia" or Nothing
```

Also, let whatever *calls* `productCountry` worry about if they need a placeholder country name should they get back `Nothing`.

Comment: Interesting! But could you please explain what you mean by "you are unnecessarily avoiding Maybe's monad instance" (newbie question!). Why is it better for function 'productCountry' to have the signature 'Product -> Maybe String' instead of 'Maybe Product -> String'

Comment: Kleisli arrows (functions with type `a -> m b` for some monad `m`) compose; functions like `m a -> b` do not. Strive for composability.